# clustering pairs of related objects

Tags: cluster-analysis

the input is :thousands of pairs of objects representing audio sync points and strength -> example

- A->B (offset 5.6 sec. strength of crossmatch:

  80%)
- D->E (offset 3.4 sec strength of crossmatch:60%)
- B->C (offset 1.0 sec strength of crossmatch:90%)
- C->D (offset 2.0 sec strength of crossmatch 60%)
- B->D (OFFSET (2-1) 1.0 SEC STRENGTH 90%)

========================================

the output should be(ideally): clusters of synced objects , with inter cluster strength cut off option.

I would appreciate your effort if you can help with this, or any guidance as to how I could get the best results.

Answer (score 0):

Try approaching this as a **clique detection** problem rather than clustering.

You sync points are edges, and you appear to be looking (your question is not very clear here) for multiple locations that are all similar, i.e. cliques.

Comment: hi there, thanks :)  basically all clips will be related to each other (most of relations are false positives) so all objects have relation (SYNC, and STRENGTH) , but as they are interdependant, meaning if clip A is in sync with clip C, and clip B is in sync with clip A AND B, the SYNC point, must be logical, to satisfy the other sync points. here's an image of clips actual timeline https://www.dropbox.com/s/0vxb3q5qaxlb7aj/Screen%20Shot%202016-07-30%20at%206.25.51%20PM.png?dl=0